# Scaling a whole plot

Tags: plot

Have a plot diagram with x and y axis and i want to scale it such as stratching.

How do i do that?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$]
%Below the red parabola is defined

%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))};
\label{$sin((x))$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$cos(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$sin(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$cos(x)$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Do not stretch the plot. Just use `\pgfplotsset{width=...,height=...}` to get the desired dimensions. You can also add `width=...,height=...` to the options of the axis. The problem is here, like in some of the questions before, that you do not provide a complete document. So it is hard to write an explicit answer. The choices depend on what you use in your document.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to stretch a pgf plot is to increase its width. (Also, as Torbjørn T. told you, it is better to write `\sin` to typeset a sine function.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} %<- you may want to add this

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$]
%Below the red parabola is defined

%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))};
\label{$sin((x))$} %<- dangerous practice
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$\cos(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$\sin(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$\cos(x)$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,% <- added
    height=5cm,% <- added
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$]
%Below the red parabola is defined

%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(x))};
\label{sin-2} %<- less dangerous 
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$\cos(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {sin(deg(2*x))};
\addlegendentry{$\sin(2x)$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:9.5, 
    samples=700, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {cos(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$\cos(x)$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the second plot is "stretched" because the width was increased and the height decreased.